# Create Here API Android Request Id?

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using the Here API for Android and I'm trying to calculate multiple routes.
I'm using **RouteManager**'s **calculateRoute** method  in order to do this.

The problem is that when using this method for multiple route calculations, the response is async and I want to be able to identify which response is for which request.

I found that for the REST API it's possible to do this by passing RequestId:

> "Clients may pass in an arbitrary string to trace request processing through the system. The RequestId is mirrored in the MetaInfo element of the response structure."

Is there something similar for the Android SDK or do I have to compare GeoCoordinates or other route specific data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HERE Maps for Android API does not provide this functionality directly but you can write some code on top of the APIs to accomplish this.

As an idea you could implement a class which extends the `RouteManager#Listener` interface and assign an ID to that class. Then you can use a unique `Listener` for every request with a different ID value.